# PHP - How to display results based on date range input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date, datetime

I have following table which displays item name,check in and check out datetime for item, and its quantities. The results are retrieved from database.(These values are for example only).

```
Item |      CheckIn       |      Checkout      | Quantity
-----|--------------------|--------------------|----------
  A  | 10-10-2015 10:40:46|                    |    20
  A  |                    | 10-10-2015 16:17:35|    7
  B  | 10-10-2015 16:35:15|                    |    25
  A  | 12-10-2015 11:13:49|                    |    5
  B  |                    | 13-10-2015 11:20:25|    10
  B  | 14-10-2015 10:38:04|                    |    3
  A  | 14-10-2015 13:00:04|                    |    30
```

And I have second table in other page which I want to display item name,date,and total quantity. What I want to do is to display result in second table based on date range input by user. Besides that, I want to automatically calculate quantity based on check in and check out process. For example, if item check in, quantity of the item is added up to current quantity of that item. If item check out, quantity of the item is subtracted from current quantity of that item.

The expected result for the second table should look like this:

a) for example user input date range (from 10.10.2015 to 12.10.2015)

```
Item Name |      Date      | Total Quantity
----------|----------------|---------------
    A     |   10.10.2015   |       13
    B     |   10.10.2015   |       25
    A     |   12.10.2015   |       5
```

The date range input is get from two input boxes (Date From and Date To) and I use Jquery datepicker. However, nothing display when I submit on date range. The problem is, there are two **datetime** fields in database which is checkIn and checkOut, and I want to display **DATE** only based on date range input by user irrespective of checking in or out. For now, no results displayed when I submit any date range. So, my question is, how to display the results based on date range input and automatically calculate total quantity.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script>
$(function() {
       $( "#from" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
       $( "#to" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
</script>

<label>Date From : </label>
<input name="from" id="from" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['from'])) echo $_GET['from']; ?>" placeholder="Select Date"  required />
<label>Date To : </label>
<input name="to" id="to" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['to'])) echo $_GET['to']; ?>" placeholder="Select Date"  required />
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />

<table>
     <tr>
    <td>ITEM NAME</td>
    <td>DATE</td>
    <td>QUANTITY</td>
    </tr>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['from'])){
    $from = $_GET['from'];
    $to = $_GET['to'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itemloc WHERE DATE(itemLocCheckIn) >= " . $from . " AND DATE(itemLocCheckIn) <=  " . $to . " OR DATE(itemLocCheckOut) >= " . $from . " AND DATE(itemLocCheckOut) <=  " . $to . "");
}

else{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itemloc");
}

$totalqty=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $date=date($row['itemLocCheckIn']);
    $item=$row['itemNm'];

    if(!isset($totalqty[$item]))
    {
    $totalqty[$item] = 0;
    }
    if(is_null($row['itemLocCheckOut'])){
        $totalqty[$item]+= $row['itemLocQty'];
    }
    else{
        $totalqty[$item]-= $row['itemLocQty'];
    }
}

foreach($totalqty as $k1=>$v1){
    ?>  
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $k1;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $date;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $v1;?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Fwiw, If in and out are on separate rows, I would have single datetime column, and an in/out column

Comment: @Strawberry , unfortunately I can't do like that because the database is fixed

Comment: check if the solution suites you please